# Visual Basic/ Access Error 424 Object Required

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making short calculation in VBA that counts the amount of Tuesdays, Thursdays, Saturdays and Sundays in two time intervals.  I keep getting various errors, but to the best of my knowledge the code is sound.  I'd appreciate any help or revisions.  Specifically I think my DatePart() might be flawed

```
Public Function ModWeekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, ByRef OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ByRef ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim numWeekdays As Integer
    Dim totalDays As Integer
    Dim totaldays2 As Integer
    Dim WeekendDays As Integer
    Dim WeekendDays2 As Integer
    numWeekdays = 0
    WeekendDays = 0
    WeekendDays2 = 0

    'totalDays = DateDiff(Day, NotificationDate, OrderDate) + 1

    'for i as integer = 1 to totalDays

        If DatePart(Day, NotificationDate) = 1 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, startDateNotificationDate) = 3 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, NotificationDate) = 5 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, NotificationDate) = 7 Then
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End If
            NotificationDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NotificationDate)
            '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     totaldays2 = DateDiff(dateinterval.Day, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate) + 1

        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 1 Then
            WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 3 Then
            WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 5 Then
            WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
        End If
        If DatePart(dateinterval.Weekday, PlacementDate) = 7 Then
            WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
        End If
            PlacementDate = DateAdd("d", 1, PlacementDate)

                        numWeekdays = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2

                        Dim MyReturnVal As Integer
MyReturnVal = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, OrderDate, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate)


End Function
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you done which makes you think there are errors? We can't read your mind.

Comment: When I try to compile it, there are numerous errors.  the first I encounter is that the "day" in the DatePart() is highlighted, and there is an error message saying 424 object required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the MS documentation --

DatePart(interval, date[,firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]])

The DatePart function syntax has these named arguments:

interval Required. String expression that is the interval of time you want to return.

date Required. Variant (Date) value that you want to evaluate.

firstdayofweek Optional. A constant that specifies the first day of the week. If not specified, Sunday is assumed.

firstweekofyear Optional. A constant that specifies the first week of the year. If not specified, the first week is assumed to be the week in which January 1 occurs.

Settings

The interval argument has these settings:

Setting Description

```
yyyy Year 
q Quarter 
m Month 
y Day of year 
d Day 
w Weekday 
ww Week 
h Hour 
n Minute 
s Second
```

The first problem line of code is corrected to--

```
    'If DatePart(Day, NotificationDate) = 1 Then
    If DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 1 Then
```

likewise for the remaining, put in "w" or "d", if that is what you want.

Lastly, check the input args for accuracy.  My sample args quickly produced the error  "out of memory" due to the recursive nature of the algorithm.
tkx